# How to set 1280x720 screen resolution in Win7 on DELL Latitude?

Tags: windows-7, resolution, dell-latitude

I am on WIndows 7, using a DELL Latitude, I have the same concern as the user who posted [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/519324/how-do-i-force-windows-8-into-1280x720).

I would like to set 1280x720 as my resolution, this is because I would like to record full screen video tutorials tu put on YOuTUbe wihtout stretching the recordings (thing I am currently doing).

I don't see 1280x720 as a supported mode.

I also tried the registry trick Display1_DownScalingSupported described in the linked quesion (the last answer speaks of that), but with no result.

Can you help me?

Comment: Could you tell us the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't see 1280x720 as a supported mode.

If you do not see it as supported mode by your video card then you are out of luck.

You might try to get new drivers from Dell.

Comment: I did i,  installed lates driver for my INtel HD Graphics 3000 and now I have only 4 supported resolutions :(

Comment: sorry, you could go back (revert driver install)