# Internet Explorer 11 in a terminal (kiosk) with low resolution

Tags: windows-8.1, terminal, internet-explorer, resolution, kiosk

We are currently using Porteus Kiosk (Linux) on our terminals. The terminal boots and starts with Firefox open on the default page (our client’s web address). Now we are considering switching to Windows terminals, partly because of the possibility of using touch gestures.

One of the problems is that our terminals have a resolution of 1024 x 600. Is there any way to start Internet Explorer (or maybe another browser, such as Firefox or Chrome) with this low resolution in kiosk mode? Sadly, it says that 1024x748 is needed... When I try to run `iexplore -k my.website.com`, Windows says that application cannot be opened, screen resolution is too low for opening this application

Comment: I'm trying this with actual terminal used for testing. When I try to run iexplore -k http://my.website.com, Windows says that application cannot be opened, screen resolution is too low for opening this application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I force windows 8 into 1280x720?](http://superuser.com/questions/519324/how-do-i-force-windows-8-into-1280x720)